# What happens to a Telegram Channel when the creator account destructs?

Tags: telegram

Suppose a Telegram channel with a Creator and some Administrator accounts managing the channels.
The creator does not log in to telegram for some months and his account destructs.

The administrators does not have some Creator privileges(for e.g. adding bots). What happens to this channel? How to get back the creator privileges?

Answer (score 2):

If you (or Telegram) use Telegram account [self-destruction](https://telegram.org/faq#q-how-does-account-self-destruction-work) **your channels will still exist** (see screenshoot).

Consider [contacting Telegram support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673024/telegram-support-phone-numbers-list) to solve your issue.

[Source](https://telegram.me/geekschannel/603)

[image: Telegram channel]

Comment: I have tried to contact telegram support for several times, both with email and contact form. I've also tried the bot support feature which has been said to be done by volunteers but there is nobody there to even read my messages!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, little has changed in the support situation. The support at Telegram is always very busy and either answers late or he likes to sit things out.