# Telegram support phone numbers list

Tags: telegram, phone-number

I'm creating a bot to redirect you to Telegram Support and I need all Telegram support contact list. Is there any accurated list with phone numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I follow a web page where they give advice and information about telegram, it is called **telegramgeeks** and I found this list that is so acurated in this [link](http://telegramgeeks.com/2016/03/contacting-telegram-support/)

You can see the list in the following photo

[image]